# External table in HIVE - Escaping double quotes from original data set

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a file with string and int values. All strings are in enclosed using " "

```
int_value1, "string_value2", int_value3, "string_value4"
```

What parameter do I need to use while creating `EXTERNAL TABLE` in HIVE to get all string without " ?

Regards
Pawel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?. change the table to external as per your need.

```
input.txt
100,  "string1", 200,  "string2"
300,  "string3", 400,  "string4"

hive> CREATE TABLE test_regex(  
    > ivalue1 STRING,  
    > svalue1 STRING,  
    > ivalue2 STRING,  
    > svalue2 STRING)  
    > ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'  
    > WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("input.regex" = "^([0-9]+),\\s+\"(.*)\",\\s+([0-9]+),\\s+\"(.*)\"$","output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s") 
    > STORED AS TEXTFILE;
OK
Time taken: 1.091 seconds

hive> load data local inpath 'input.txt' overwrite into table test_regex;
OK
Time taken: 0.391 seconds

hive> select *from test_regex;
OK
100 string1 200 string2
300 string3 400 string4
Time taken: 0.212 seconds
hive>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could either use [csv-serde](https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde) or [regex-serde](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/trunk/contrib/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/serde2/RegexSerDe.java) to achieve what you are looking for.